# How many people actually died during The War of the Five Kings?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

If I understand correctly, before the events of the first season (or book) the population of the Seven Kingdoms was about half a million or so?

But how bloody was the Clash of The kings, and how populated is the kingdom now, after five seasons?

Comment: Why do you think it was half a million?

Comment: Because Kingslayer mentioned that.

Comment: Do you recall which book/chapter?  I find this number a bit hard to believe... We see armies of tens of thousands in the War of 5 Kings. The total number of fighting men in the war must be over 100,000. Given that, the total population of 500,000 seems way too low.

Comment: In 3rd season Jaimie Lannister said to one healer in response to question "How many people have you saved?". He said "700 thousands - the population of the seven kingdoms". Not sure if he was referring to the population during Roberts' rebellion or the current one.

Comment: Well, 700,000 is a bit more believable than half a million. :)

Comment: The seven kingdoms are supposed to be as large as *South America*, with King's Landing itself accounting for tens of thousands of people (Didn't Jaime refer to the city, not the kingdoms, btw?). A population of 700k is ridiculously low. Even a total population of 10 million would make it extremely sparsely settled. Compare mediaeval Europe at 100-200 million while being smaller, but also more fertile than Westeros. Regardless what the books actually say, 1 million is far too low.

Comment: @Chieron, on the other hand, a population of 700k people is far too high for a medieval city.

Comment: Compared to the capitals of the Arab world, it's not that bad. Baghdad had close to a million. A few European cities had more than 100k. King's Landing is the capital of a continent-spanning empire, after all.   In general, these numbers are problematic, because G.R.R. Martin obviously didn't thoroughly check for plausibility.  BTW, the population density of Westeros at 500k pop with South American area would be close to Greenland.

Comment: Is "The War of the Five Kings" over yet? (In the books...) When Renly died, there were only four kings left an that's the end? Or, do we continue until there is only one: as long as Stannis, Euron, and Tommen all claim to be kings, it is not finished. If it is not finished, then we cannot answer this question.

Answer (score 39):

## tl;dr: Hundreds of thousands, but not millions.

---

**Current calculated total: ~152,262 - 343,106.**

---

To begin with, there are a couple of misconceptions here which need to be cleared up first:

1. The population of the Seven Kingdoms was *much* higher than half a million.

   - In fact, according to westeros.org:

     > The population of the Seven Kingdoms numbers in the **millions**. 
     > <sup>*-http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Seven_Kingdoms#Population*</sup>
   - Here's a cool graphic which illustrates the rough population, from [this article](http://www.dailydot.com/geek/game-of-thrones-westeros-mapped/):
     [image: Image depicting rough population of Westeros. From: http://cdn0.dailydot.com/uploaded/images/original/2014/5/17/fern_draft4a.png]
     src: http://cdn0.dailydot.com/uploaded/images/original/2014/5/17/fern_draft4a.png
2. Jaime did not save the entirety of Westeros (at least not directly), he saved King's Landing, from the [Wildfire Plot](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Wildfire_plot).

   - King's Landing has a population of about half a million.
   - I believe you are referring to [this scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JZ6fhp483YU) from *[Game of Thrones: Season Three, Episode Seven (The Bear and the Maiden Fair)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2178814/?ref_=ttep_ep7)*; wherein Jaime specifically tells Qyburn that he has [saved the population of King's Landing](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Jaime_Lannister#Kingslayer) (1/2 million people).

---

## Break-it-down

**[The War of the Five Kings](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/War_of_the_Five_Kings)** was a war involving the following "belligerents":

1. **The King on the Iron Throne**: [Joffrey Baratheon](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Joffrey_Baratheon)
2. **The King in The North and The Trident**: [Robb Stark](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Robb_Stark)
3. **The King in the Narrow Sea**: [Stannis Baratheon](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Stannis_Baratheon)
4. **The King in Highgarden**: [Renly Baratheon](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Renly_Baratheon)
5. **The King of the Isles and the North**: [Balon Greyjoy](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Balon_Greyjoy)

The war was ignited when Catelyn captured Tyrion on suspicions that Tyrion had attempted to murder the crippled Bran, after his fall.

There were a few battles/clashes within this war, namely:

### The War in the Riverlands

A pre-cursor to the Stark vs. Lannister wars. Jaime starts attacking the Riverlands and heads towards Riverrun. This is in retaliation to Tyrion's capture.

Major battles include:

- **[Gregor the Pillager](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/War_of_the_Five_Kings#The_War_in_the_Riverlands)**
  Tywin saw the act of Tyrion's capture as a disgrace to his family's honour, so he sent Gregor and his men on a pillaging mission in the Riverlands; all to lure Ned out into the Riverlands where *he* could then be captured.

  - **Total deaths: ~100-500** mostly smallfolk and castellans
- **[Battle in the hills below the Golden Tooth](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Battle_in_the_hills_below_the_Golden_Tooth)**

  - **Total deaths: ~8,000**
- **[Battle at the Mummer's Ford](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Battle_at_the_Mummer%27s_Ford)**
  Ned is injured after his sortie with Jaime at King's Landing, so he sends a small task-force lead by Beric Dondarrion to stop and capture Gregor Clegane, in the name of the King.

  - **Total deaths: 120 men**, including Lord Beric Dondarion<sup>**1**</sup>
- **[Battle under the walls of Riverrun](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Battle_under_the_walls_of_Riverrun)**
  Jaime pushes forward toward Riverrun

  - **Total deaths: ~1,000**

### The Wolf and The Lion

This is where it gets interesting. Robb Stark enters the war on behalf of the Tullys, and all hell breaks loose. Note: Robb’s main host is ~20,000 men in total and the Lannister forces are ~35,000.

Major battles include:

- **[Battle on the Green Fork](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Battle_on_the_Green_Fork)**

  - **Total deaths: ~6,000**
- **[Battle in the Whispering Wood](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Battle_in_the_Whispering_Wood)**

  - **Total deaths: ~2,000**
- **[Battle of the Camps](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Battle_of_the_Camps)**

  - **Total deaths: Not many, probably ~1,000**
- **[Long Live The King](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Robert_I_Baratheon#A_Game_of_Thrones)**
  King Robert Baratheon decides to go hunting and proceeds to get impaled by a wild boar, causing his death:

  - **Total deaths: 1**
- **[Execution of The Traitor](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/War_of_the_Five_Kings#The_Wolf_and_the_Lion)**
  Cersei Lannister and the City Watch overtake Ned Stark's personal guard and household keep from Winterfell and declare him treasonous. Ned is captured and later executed, his entire household is killed (except for Arya and Sansa):

  - **Total deaths: ~55** including the five guardsmen which Syrio Forel kills with his wooden sword and the eventual beheading of Ned Stark
- **Retreat to Harrenhall, Sack of Darry and Reclaiming of the Riverlands**
  Tywin's forces retreat to Harrenhall, destroying and pillaging any nearby towns, including raping and murdering the smallfolk.
  Robb gets declared King in the North (and the Trident) and his forces reclaim various holdfasts within the Riverlands.
  Darry is reclaimed, but is soon retaken by Gregor Clegane who puts the entire Darry household to sword.

  - **Total deaths: ~5,000 - ~10,000** mostly smallfolk

### Rise of The Kraken

Balon Greyjoy decides he wants to be **[The King of the Isles and the North](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Balon_Greyjoy#A_Clash_of_Kings)**. In order to establish his claim and solidify his influence, he orders the reavings of the coastlines. Theon decides he wants to be a Greyjoy again and to please his father, hence takes Winterfell.

Battles include:

- **[Fall of Moat Cailin](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Fall_of_Moat_Cailin)**

  - Unknown number of deaths, probably **~1,000**
- **[Taking of Deepwood Motte](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Taking_of_Deepwood_Motte)**

  - Unknown number of deaths, probably **~1,000**
- **[Harrying of the Stony Shore](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Harrying_of_the_Stony_Shore)**

  - All of the [Wild Hares](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Wild_Hares) (probably **~50**)
- **[Fight at Torrhen's Square](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Fight_at_Torrhen%27s_Square)**

  - **Total deaths: ~250**
- **[Capture of Torrhen's Square](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Capture_of_Torrhen%27s_Square)**
- **[Capture of Winterfell](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Capture_of_Winterfell)**
  This is where Theon decides to take Winterfell with his equivalent of "[twenty good men](https://www.facebook.com/ramsaysmen)"

  - **Total deaths: 5** - [Mikken](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Mikken) (Winterfell's blacksmith - he created Arya's Needle), [Alebelly](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Alebelly), [Septon Chayle](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Chayle) and the two miller's boys
- **[Battle at Winterfell](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Battle_at_Winterfell)**
  Ser Rodrik Cassell tries to reclaim Winterfell with his 600 men, but are defeated by a cunning Ramsay Snow (who was posing as Reek at the time)

  - **Total deaths: ~100** - including the execution of Ser Rodrik Cassell
- **[The Sacking of Winterfell](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Sack_of_Winterfell)**
  Ramsay ditches his "Reek" persona and has the Ironborn men killed and captures Theon, later setting fire to Winterfell and much of the Stark household.

  - **Total deaths: ~50** - including Theon's remaining 18 men, as well as [Maester Luwin](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Luwin)

### The Clash of Kings

After a short break, Robb decides to take to the offensive. He sends Cleos Frey to King's Landing with a letter of peace, but secretly attacks.

- **[Battle of Oxcross](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Battle_of_Oxcross)**
  Rob Stark takes Stevron Lannister's army by surprise

  - **Total deaths: unknown, possibly ~1,000**
- **[Taking of Ashemark](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Taking_of_Ashemark)**
  More scouring occurs, this time of the Westerlands. Robb's forces take the Castle of Ashemark and bolster his army with supplies and livestock from nearby towns.

  - **Total deaths: unknown, not significant**
- **[Siege of Storm's End (299AC)](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Siege_of_Storm%27s_End_(299))**
  Stannis besieges Renly's seat, Storm's End (the traditional seat of House Baratheon). Renly parlays with Stannis but fails to come to an agreement and set a time for the fight, for next morning. Renly however is killed that night by Stannis and Melisandre's shadow demon. Loras goes berserk mode and kills Renly's guards, Robar Royce and Emmon Cuy. Stannis moves on to take Storm's End and Ser Cortnay Penrose (castellan of Storm's End) is killed by Melisandre's shadow baby v2.0; Storm's End is surrendered.

  - **Total deaths: 4**
- **[Bitterbridge](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Bitterbridge)**
  Not a battle per se, confusion and anger takes over the 80,000 men strong camp of Renly's with Ser Loras Tyrell still deep into his berserk mode. Lord Randyll Tarly takes over, and true to himself, puts many men (mostly Florents) to death. The army is split, some defect to Stannis' side, some stay with the Tyrells and later join The Crown.

  - **Total deaths: unknown, let's say ~1,000**
- **[Battle of the Fords](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Battle_of_the_Fords)**
  Tywin is angered and decides to take matters into his own hands and marches upon Robb's host in the Westerlands. Edmure Tully hears of this and decides to cut him off. Although the victory went to Edmure with high casualties on the Lannister side, it was later revealed to have been a mistake since Robb wanted Tywin's host to enter further into the Westerlands and be unable to save King's Landing from Stannis' attack. However Tywin was able to retreat and take Stannis' army from behind. Oh, poor Edmure.

  - **Total deaths: ~5,000**
- **[Fall of Harrenhal](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Fall_of_Harrenhal)**
  Roose's men set upon Harrenhall, which is presently occupied by Amory Lorch and Vargo Hoat (and the Brave Companions).

  - **Total deaths: 100**
- **[Storming of the Crag](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Storming_of_the_Crag)**
  This is where Robb gets injured and meets Jeyne Westerling

  - **Total deaths: very low, perhaps only 1** (killed by Grey Wind)
- **[Battle of the Blackwater](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Battle_of_the_Blackwater)**
  This one's the big one! Lots of parties, and lots of casualties. Most of Stannis' fleet as well as a majority of The Crown's fleet was nuked to oblivion by Tyrion's infamous [wildfire plot](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Battle_of_the_Blackwater#Battle_on_the_River).

  - Total deaths: countless
  - **at minimum: 7,283 confirmed**
  - **at maximum: ~94,000**

### The War Winds Down

After Stannis' defeat at Blackwater and the Ironborn taking castles in The North, including Winterfell, Robb is forced to retreat and protect his homeland.

Major battles include:

- **[Battle at Duskendale](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Battle_at_Duskendale)**

  - **Total deaths: ~1,500**
- **[Battle at the burning septry](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Battle_at_the_burning_septry)**

  - **Total deaths: 101 to 201**
- **[Fighting at the fords of the Trident](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Fighting_at_the_fords_of_the_Trident)**

  - **Total deaths: ~2,000**
- **[Capture of Harrenhal](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Capture_of_Harrenhal)**

  - **Total deaths: ~50**
- **[Taking of Maidenpool](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Taking_of_Maidenpool)**

  - **Total deaths: unknown**
- **[The Red Wedding](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Red_Wedding)**
  Do I have to? Please? Okay...
  Robb is forced to reconcile with Walder Frey since they need to use his crossing to get back to The North. Walder agrees to reconcile on condition that Edmure marries one of his daughters (Roslin). However, Roose Bolton and Tywin have arranged for a massacre of Robb's army during said wedding, to which Walder happily obliges.

  - **Total deaths: ~3,500** + Grey Wind, Dacey Mormont, Catelyn Stark, Robb Stark, and too many others to count.

### The Feasting Crows

The Lannisters think they've assured their victory, however there are still major undercover plots being enacted.

Major events include:

- **[The Purple Wedding](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Purple_Wedding)**
  Admit it, you cheered didn't you?

  - **Total deaths: 2** (Joffrey and Ser Dontos)
- [**Trial of Tyrion Lannister**](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Tyrion_Lannister#A_Storm_of_Swords)
  Tyrion gets blamed for the Purple Wedding and is put on trial. He demands a Trial By Battle in which Prince Oberyn Martell [volunteers as tribute](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y3RlalRV4S8) and the Crown names Ser Gregor Clegane as its Champion. Oberyn promptly decides to get impaled and has his face crushed-in, but not before poisoning The Mountain causing his delayed death.

  - **Total deaths: 2**
- **[Death of Tywin Lannister](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Tywin_Lannister#A_Storm_of_Swords)**
  After getting jail-broken by his brother Jaime, Tyrion decides he's not going to leave things in peace; he sneaks into his Pa's bed chambers, finds Shae, chokes her and proceeds to conduct a scientific-experiment to determine whether Tywin Lannister truly shits gold. [He didn't](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/273665-lord-tywin-lannister-did-not-in-the-end-shit-gold).

  - **Total deaths: 2**
- **[Attacks of Lady Stoneheart](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Brotherhood_without_banners#A_Feast_for_Crows)**
  Lady Stoneheart is created and takes over the Brotherhood Without Banners. Starts wreacking havoc on the Riverlands and gets revenge on Freys and Lannisters like they're tree ornamentss.

  - **Total deaths: 3-~20**
- **[The Battle of Castle Black](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Battle_of_Castle_Black)**
  This one's another big one. Mance decides that the best place to hide from the oncoming Others is behind the Great Big Magical Ice Wall. However, he thinks the best way to do this is to attack and kill the current residents - the Uber-Emo Night's Watchmen. During his attack though, Stannis The Mannis decides he's having none of it and takes Mance's army from the flanks.

  - **Total deaths: 2,225 - 2,235** (including Mag The Mighty, Ygritte, Harma, Styr and Donal Noye)
- **[Siege of Moat Cailin](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Siege_of_Moat_Cailin)**

  - **Total deaths: 67**
- **Raid on Saltpans**

  - **Total deaths: entire town of Saltpans, maybe ~100**
- **[fight by Deepwood Motte](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Fight_by_Deepwood_Motte)**

  - **Total deaths: 191**
- **[Taking of The Shields](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Taking_of_the_Shields)**

  - **Total deaths: ~500**
- **[Siege of Dragonstone](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Siege_of_Storm%27s_End_(300))**

  - **Total deaths: ~1,000**

### Nobles

There were [186 confirmed nobles](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Category:Casualties_of_the_War_of_the_Five_Kings) killed during The War of The Five Kings.

### Famine

The main factor in this horrible war is most definitely **famine**. People are dying day-by-day, and food stores as well as farms are being depleted or put to the torch.

Even in the capital, King's Landing, it's becoming ever more difficult to get food; good quality food that isn't filled with people's shoes or people's flesh.

In a harsh [Famine Winter](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Famine_Winter), there can be as much as three times the number of deaths from famine as previous wars<sup>[[1]](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Famine_Winter#cite_note-Rtwoiaf_the_black_blood.7B.7B.7B3.7D.7D.7D-0)</sup>, therefore:

- **Total deaths: ~100,000**

### Future

Winter is coming. Most towns and cities don't have enough food stores and this winter is going to be a harsh one, both with the threat of the White Walkers and the impending Dance of Dragons; it's going to get even bloodier!

---

<sup>**1.** Yes, he gets revived later on by Thoros of Myr; count this as his *first* death.</sup>

Comment: I wish i could upvote twice ! nice answer.

Comment: Does your famine estimate include the civilians killed in pillaging the riverlands?

Comment: @user568458 No, those are included in the section "Retreat to Harrenhall, Sack of Darry and Reclaiming of the Riverlands".

Comment: Ah, I was thinking about the pillaging before the war fully broke out, while Ned was still standing in for Robert - the provocation that led injured Ned to dispatch Dondarrion and company to arrest Clegane. So, the previous section "The War in the Riverlands" but Gregor's pillaging in addition to Jaime's battles. Represented in the TV show with a peasant dumping fish at Ned's feet

Comment: @user568458 Oh, I see what you meant. Yeah, I thought about that, but I don't think that officially, the Wot5K had started by then; it was more of a pre-cursor which all started with the capture of Tyrion. I will do some estimates and see if it's feasible to include those skirmishes (including the Battle at the Gates of The Moon and Tyrion's trial)...

Comment: @yondaime008 Thank you, that's very kind.

Comment: Ah, yeah, good point. I guess it's one of these matters of perspective, like how [some people call Franz Ferdinand the first casualty of WW1](http://www.encyclopedia.com/article-1G2-3411700037/franz-ferdinand.html) while others would strongly disagree.

Comment: Wow. Just wow. That bounty will be very well deserved.

Comment: Does the Red Wedding factor into this too?

Comment: “Tywin saw the act of Tyrion's capture as a disgrace to his family's honour, so he sent Gregor and his men on a pillaging mission” — I must restore my family’s honour! By sending a team of men to steal, rape and destroy their way through the country I live in and wish to rule!

Comment: @PaulD.Waite `"Some tasks are fit for lions, ... but foraging is best left for goats and dogs.”` - Tywin

Comment: @user568458 Thank you for the bounty. Much appreciated!

Comment: @Paul Wow! Thanks so much for the huge bounty. My biggest one yet!

Comment: @Mooz: you’re very most welcome, this answer is a great piece of research.