# Standard map of the whole realm with all cities in Game of Thrones?

Tags: game-of-thrones, map

I have searched all over internet for exact map of Game of Thrones cities. But every map is different from each other and rather confuses me as they have embedded story-line into it. Can anybody give a link/photograph/illustration of complete map of Game of Thrones with all mentioned cities of seven kingdoms of westeros and also Essos and Sothoryos?

This question is different from [Why are there no maps of lands east of Westeros in The Game of Thrones?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11503/why-are-there-no-maps-of-lands-east-of-westeros-in-the-game-of-thrones)

because I disagree that the map does not exist: Here it is:
http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/File:WorldofIceandFire.png

But this map lacks details of isolation of seven kingdoms in westeros, regions of Essos and Sothoryos.

In a nutshell, I need a one political map instead of many scattered political maps.

Reference: http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Portal:Geography

Comment: Do you just want the 7 kingdoms or all the Known World ?

Comment: Map of all known world with location of cities with depiction of seven kingdoms.

Comment: What about the maps in the books?

Comment: @bon If you can post a picture from the book that does the work it would be great

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114440/what-exists-beyond-westeros-north-of-the-wall-and-the-free-cities

Comment: You won't find any exact maps. GRRM has intentionally left such things vague since he doesn't want to be bogged down by accuracy of maps. There are however very "officially sanctioned" artists impressions which are available. For example: [The Known World](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Known_world) and [The Lands of Ice and Fire](http://www.fantasticmaps.com/the-lands-of-ice-and-fire/)

Comment: @mooz I think its not duplicate as I am asking for whole map and not for lands only East of westeros.

Comment: there are no official maps. only the fan created ones and that is why they all look different!

Comment: @rocktopus [dlanod's answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/11506/21267) specifies that there are the "official" maps of the whole world.

Comment: @Mooz: Yes, I agree that book (https://www.amazon.com/Lands-Ice-Fire-Game-Thrones/dp/0345538544/187-1694971-3500936?ie=UTF8&tag=stackoverfl08-20) may contain the answer to my query. But is it anyone who can find the map in that book? ;)

Comment: Are you saying that you just want the map your linked to on awoiaf.westeros.org but with the borders of the seven kingdoms drawn in? You could probably do that yourself.

Comment: I agree with Mooz here. That answer (and book) is the one you are looking for. VTC as duplicate because of existing answer.

Comment: @blackwood: That's what my question is, if there is already an official map available as discussed with Mooz, we just have to find it or upload it. It's highly unlikely I can make one better than the official one.

Comment: There is an app called "A World of Ice and Fire" (android and iOS) and it has a map of the entire known world that is labeled and can be zoomed in. Not exactly what you're asking for but it's also very nice because you can tap on cities and landmarks and get details about them.

Comment: @Virusbomb your answers is exactly what is expected. Thanks.